# Partial view is not loading in pagecontainer class on click of Basic Info button in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my code for design this UI
[UI here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tsjw.png)

```
<div>
    <div class="py-2 h4">
        Profile Setting Page
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 bg-light py-2">
            <div class="p-1" >
                <a href="/Profile/BasicInfo" class="btn btn-dark w-100" id="basicinfo">Basic Info</a>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 bg-light">
            <div class="pagecontainer">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-4">
                    <h1 class="display-3">Welcome to Settings</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the above code, use the 'pagecontainer' class for loading the partial UI. After clicking on 'Basic Info' button, partial view page loading but doesn't insert in pagecontainer class , it is refreshed and shows on same page like this,[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egsuL.png)
My JavaScript code is as,

```
//basic info
    $("#basicinfo").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        $.get(href, function (data, status) {
            $('.pagecontainer').html(data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I believe when you click on the link page will be refreshed so that content is not bonded in `pagecontainer` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

In your HTML just replace `anchor` tag `href` attribute with this `javascript:void(0);`

add one attribute it's up to whatever want you can add.
Like example I've added the `data-url="/Profile/BasicInfo"`

```
<div>
    <div class="py-2 h4">
        Profile Setting Page
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 bg-light py-2">
            <div class="p-1" >
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-url="/Profile/BasicInfo" class="btn btn-dark w-100" id="basicinfo">Basic Info</a>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 bg-light">
            <div class="pagecontainer">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-4">
                    <h1 class="display-3">Welcome to Settings</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Jquery

```
//basic info
$("#basicinfo").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).data("url");
    $.get(href, function (data, status) {
        $('.pagecontainer').html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove href from tag a:

```
<div class="p-1" >
  <a  class="btn btn-dark w-100" id="basicinfo">Basic Info</a>
</div>
```

and in the javascript:

```
$("#basicinfo").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();   
    $.get("/Profile/BasicInfo", function (data, status) {
        $('.pagecontainer').html(data);
    });
});
```